# C# WPF Binding метода

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть метод

```
InputLanguageManager.Current.CurrentInputLanguage.TwoLetterISOLanguageName
```

возвращает текущий язык. Как сделать чтобы каждый раз когда изменяется язык изменялся View?

Comment: `InputLanguageManager.Current.CurrentInputLanguage.TwoLetterISOLanguageName` - это разве метод?

Comment: ой, ну вобщем поле)

Comment: `каждый раз когда изменяется язык` - вы это событие можете отловить?